# Split the data then insert a new separator

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is the any ways to insert a word after replace and split the data?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({1: ['420,03', '20.0420,20', '7,420.00']})

print (df)
            1
0      420,03
1  20.0420,20
2    7,420.00


df[2] = df[1].replace(',','',regex = True).replace('\.','',regex = True)

print (df)
0       42003
1    20042020
2      742000


df = df[1].str.split('')

print (df)
0                [, 4, 2, 0, ,, 0, 3, ]
1    [, 2, 0, ., 0, 4, 2, 0, ,, 2, 0, ]
2          [, 7, ., 4, 2, 0, ,, 0, 0, ]
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

the result wanted is as below: where there is dot from right 3

```
0       420.03
1    200420.20
2      7420.00
```

Comment: replace dot with nothing, replace coma with dot?

Comment: just use strings replace

Comment: do you read from csv? `df.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\t', thousands=',')`

Comment: `df[2] = df[1].str.replace('.', '').str.replace(',', '.')`

Comment: cannot because some of my data will be in already have dot in the third from left

Comment: ``df.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\t', thousands=',')`` it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe also use the `decimal` keyword: `df.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\t', thousands='.', decimal=',')`

Comment: Use this after your replace function `df[2] = (df[2].str[:-2]+'.'+df[2].str[-2:])`

Comment: ```df[2] = (df[2].str[:-2]+'.'+df[2].str[-2:])``` this works for me~ thanks!